# Check all table columns for a value

Tags: h2

Ok, tricky question I am trying to figure out where a database schema is storing a particular pointer.  I know the pointer value I just don't what table it is in or what column.  I know the pointer is 123123123.  How do I check all table columns to see if any of them have that value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In h2 you can use [fulltext search](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html?highlight=fulltext&search=fullt#fulltext), but then you would need to add all tables in the search scope and indexing.

If you need to index only primary keys, then it might be better but you still need to come up with individual `FT_CREATE_INDEX()` calls for each table. You can automate this with several languages or with ETLs (like [scriptella](http://scriptella.org/)).

If you've enough disk space, you could dump a SQL from your db and use a viewer for big files like [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/).

The advantage of the first solution is no external tools but you need to work out a specific indexing script for SQL for any existing or new table. The 2nd solution is a 1 time fix.

Comment: what I did was a dump of the DB and then used globb to just text search.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use SQL Search from RedGate. It's free and it helps you find any text anywhere in the database.

https://www.red-gate.com/products/?gclid=CjwKEAjwiYG9BRCkgK-G45S323oSJABnykKAE7IH_EMhnmq7OdLdXljfIkdGZrDD6OnOrT4VB0agahoCVn3w_wcB